# De-serialize JSON using JSON.net on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm trying to grab some JSON data from a web service using JSON.Net. The error I'm getting is an unexpected character whilst parsing the json data. The code i'm using is as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
WebResponse response;

private void btnGet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://http://domain.com/test/question.php") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.BeginGetResponse(AfterRequest, null);
}

private void AfterRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
    using (StreamReader sd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string resultString = sd.ReadToEnd();

        Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(resultString);
        response.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(values["Question"]);
    }
}
```

The data I'm trying to de-serialize is:

```
{"Question":"How old am i?","A":"20","B":"23","C":"25","D":"26","Z":"D"}
```

This data is outputted via php/mysql. Any idea's if it's my code or the JSON data that's invalid?

thanks
**EDIT:** I've updated the data i'm trying to de-serialize, it now looks like this;`{
    "Question": "How old am i?",
    "Answers": {
        "A": "24",
        "B": "25",
        "C": "26",
        "D": "27"
    },
    "Answer": "B"
}`

Comment: Have you debugged and saw that "resultString" variable has that json data?

Comment: I would suggest writing a test program to output the required json when serialized from json.net

Comment: did you managed to resolve this ? if yes, please post the solution here. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is "valid" but it is poorly formed to get the results you are looking for. I'd change the formatting of your JSON to such:

```
{
 "Question":"How old am i?",
 "Answers":[
   "A":"20",
   "B":"23",
   "C":"25",
   "D":"26",
   "Z":"D"]
}
```

By moving your possible answers into an array you make it easier to keep them separated from the question, and also make it so you can extend the data set to include items such as "CorrectAnswer":"B"

Comment: I've altered my Json, I've updated my first post. With JSON.NET should i be using dictionary or some other option?

Comment: I apologize, I should have read through your code a little better before answering. If you want to dump it into a Dictionary<string, string> you'll need to format the JSON as such: [{"key":"A","value":"20"},{"key":"B","value":"23"}...]